# read file record by record and do transformation to the subsequent record based on above record and write into another file

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing

Data file is fixed length file, and I want to read the file record by record and do transformations to the subsequent records based on the prior records (and write the results into another file).

**Example**:

```
CTD1234abcdTRN0001
AA 5678defg
BB 8910erty
CTD5678qwerTRN5678
AA 9876bvcn
BB 8765zxcv
```

Now I want `TRN0001` from the `CTD` record to be written to the subsequent `AA` and `BB` records, similarly for the following `CTD` records. My output should look like:

```
CTD1234abcdTRN0001
AA 5678defgTRN0001
BB 8910ertyTRN0001
CTD5678qwerTRN5678
AA 9876bvcnTRN5678
BB 8765zxcvTRN5678
```

**Example 2:**

```
AAABBBB11115678xxxx
BBBCCCC22221234YYYY
MTD0001abcdTRN12345 abcdedfg
AA 0002bcde
BB 0003defg
CCCDDDD33331234zzzz
MTD0003qwerTRN56789 defghigk
AA 9876bvcn
BB 8765zxcv
XXXBBBB11115678aaaa
YYYCCCC22221234bbbb
```

should become

```
AAABBBB11115678xxxx
BBBCCCC22221234YYYY
MTD0001abcdTRN12345 abcdedfg
AA 0002bcdeTRN12345
BB 0003defgTRN12345
CCCDDDD33331234zzzz
MTD0003qwerTRN56789 defghigk
AA 9876bvcnTRN56789
BB 8765zxcvTRN56789
XXXBBBB11115678aaaa
YYYCCCC22221234bbbb
```

Can you please help me on this, how can you achieve this using UNIX shell scripting?

Comment: Can you be more precise about the structure of the file? Are there exactly two records of each type per line. Is the substring in question fixed in length, e.g the last 7 characters of the CTD field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat testdata
CTD1234abcdTRN0001
AA 5678defg
BB 8910erty
CTD5678qwerTRN5678
AA 9876bvcn
BB 8765zxcv
CTDxxxxxxxxTRNyyyy
AA foobarfo
BB foobarfo
AAABBBB11115678xxxx
BBBCCCC22221234YYYY
MTD0001abcdTRN12345 abcdedfg
AA 0002bcde
BB 0003defg
CCCDDDD33331234zzzz
MTD0003qwerTRN56789 defghigk
AA 9876bvcn
BB 8765zxcv
XXXBBBB11115678aaaa
YYYCCCC22221234bbbb

$ awk '/^(C|M)TD/ { s=match($0, /[[:space:]]/); postfix=substr($0, 12, length($0)-s); print; next } /^(AA|BB)[[:space:]]/ { print $0 postfix; next } 1' testdata
CTD1234abcdTRN0001
AA 5678defgTRN0001
BB 8910ertyTRN0001
CTD5678qwerTRN5678
AA 9876bvcnTRN5678
BB 8765zxcvTRN5678
CTDxxxxxxxxTRNyyyy
AA foobarfoTRNyyyy
BB foobarfoTRNyyyy
AAABBBB11115678xxxx
BBBCCCC22221234YYYY
MTD0001abcdTRN12345 abcdedfg
AA 0002bcdeTRN12345
BB 0003defgTRN12345
CCCDDDD33331234zzzz
MTD0003qwerTRN56789 defghigk
AA 9876bvcnTRN56789
BB 8765zxcvTRN56789
XXXBBBB11115678aaaa
YYYCCCC22221234bbbb
```

Comment: there may be multiple CTD line in a file

Comment: And you want the first CTD line's TRNxxxx to carry into _all_ subsequent AA and BB records (and ignore any following CTD lines)?

Comment: The above output I need and there may be multiple CTD line in file...

Comment: You fail to explain how the output should look with more than two CTD lines in a file. I updated my answer with what I assume you are asking for.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry my output should look like:                                          CTD1234abcdTRN0001
AA 5678defgTRN0001
BB 8910ertyTRN0001
CTD5678qwerTRN5678
AA 9876bvcnTRN5678
BB 8765zxcvTRN5678
CTDxxxxxxxxTRNyyyy
AA foobarfoTRNyyyy
BB foobarfoTRNyyyy

Comment: That's exactly what I had before my last edit as you did not seem satisfied with what I posted. I changed it back, is this ok now? I am starting to get really confused here ;-)

Comment: Once again thanks a lot it really worked and eased my life...

Comment: @user36697 if this answer helped you please accept it by clicking on the check mark on the left.

Comment: @user36697 Perfect! Please accept the answer and try to be a little more specific next time you ask a question here, it makes everyone's life easier :-)

Comment: Hi Adrain, In the file I will have not only CTD line and the subsequent AA and BB line, there are other lines which needs to be moved as it is, however in CTD line CTD5678qwerTRN5678  after TRN5678 there is lot of values in the line that also to be available while writing in a new file... so, how to achieve this?

Comment: @user36697 Please update your question with regards to the file format and give an example. It's Adrian, btw!

Comment: can you pls. see the example 2 above

Comment: I updated my answer. It takes suffixes from lines starting with `CTD` or `MTD`, the suffix starts at character `12` and ends at the first whitespace/end of the line. The suffix is furthermore only added to lines starting with `AA` or `BB` which are followed by a whitespace. Is this specific enough to cover all your needs?

Answer (score 2):

That the Unix shell is a (quite limited) programming language is a bonus for its job of organizing other program's work. It is *not* to be used for everything.

Such text-processing jobs are better done with scripting languages specifically created for this purpose, like Perl or Python.

Comment: so, can you pls. let me know in Perl?

Comment: @user36697 you should try to solve it yourself and ask for the specific problem you encountered.